# Huge TeamCity Database

Tags: sql-server, teamcity

We use TeamCity with a Microsoft SQL Server database which takes more than 31Go. What can we do to reduce its size and how could we troubleshoot it to prevent the database to grow even more ?
[image]

For information, we use TeamCity Professional version 2021.1.1 (build 92714) and below are our clean-up rules.
[image]

Comment: 31GB is *nothing*; in modern terms a database that size is *tiny*, not "huge". A "Huge" database would be 10's, or even 100's of TBs in size.

Comment: What are the autogrowth settings on the database files?  It could have grown automatically at some point (maybe prior to setting clean-up rules) and stayed there.

Comment: Thank you @squillman. The autogrowth is set to "by 1 MB, Unlimited". The clean-up rules have always been set and one year ago we had our first issue as the Database was exceeding the allowed size for a SQL Server Express database. That's why we moved to a real SQL server but it kept increasing...